# Error while increasing array value size by 1 error

Tags: arrays, ruby, count, increment

I'm trying to create a program that will take an input of two integers of size 10 and below, that counts the amount of carry operations as a result of summing the input integers.

For example:

Sample Input:

59864417 974709147

Sample Output:

6

The line which returns an error in my program is:

```
parta[i+1] = ( parta[i+1] + 1 )
```

There i'm trying to add 1 to the value currently in the next array position.

```
run = true

while run == true
  #input string
    text = gets.chomp
 #split string and remove space
    parta = text.split[0]
    partb = text.split[1]
#convert split strings to integers
    partf1 = parta.to_i
    partf2 = partb.to_i
#check for terminal input of 0 
      if partf1 + partf2 <= 0
          run = false
      end
#fill strings with 0s to size 11
     parta = sprintf( "%011i", parta )
     partb = sprintf( "%011i", partb )


#convert strings to arrays of integers
parta = parta.split("").map(&:to_i)
partb = partb.split("").map(&:to_i)

count = 0

(10).downto(0) do |i|

if ( parta[i] + partb[i] ) > 9
   count = count + 1
   parta[i+1] = ( parta[i+1] + 1 )
#59864417 974709147 test input should output 6
 end

end
if run == true

puts "#{count} carry operations."

end
end
```

When I run I get the following error message:

test5.ruby:42:in `block in <main>': undefined method`+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from test5.ruby:29:in `downto'
    from test5.ruby:29:in`

Could anyone help me? :)

Comment: what error you got?

Comment: Error message I get: test5.ruby:42:in `block in <main>': undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
 from test5.ruby:29:in `downto'
 from test5.ruby:29:in `<main>

Comment: I suspect there's a simpler approach overall, but for your particular issue: the highest index in the array is `10`, right? In that case, when `i` is 10, `parta[i+1]` (on the right side) is `nil`, because there's no element in the array with that index. When you try to increment `nil`, you get an error. Shouldn't it be `parta[i-1] = parta[i-1] + 1` anyway?

Comment: thank you very much Max. That fixed it! I can't believe I didn't notice that haha

Comment: Glad to help. I've expanded my comment into a slightly longer answer so that you can mark it as accepted if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding my comment into a slightly longer answer:

I suspect there's a simpler approach overall, but for your particular issue: the highest index in the array is `10`. In that case, when `i` is 10, `parta[i+1]` (on the right side) is `nil`, because there's no element in the array with that index. When you try to increment `nil`, you get an error. But it should be `parta[i-1] = parta[i-1] + 1` anyway if you're trying to go from right to left. This will cause some odd behavior when `i` is 0, but you might not care about that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on this line

```
parta[i+1] = ( parta[i+1] + 1 )
```

In case `i == size of the array` the expression `i + 1` will return `nil` which causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, here's the rewritten version with Ruby 2.4 (for `Intger#digits`):

```
a = 59_864_417
b = 974_709_147

a, b = [a, b].sort

carry = false
count = b.digits.zip(a.digits).count do |m, n|
  r = m + (n || 0) + (carry ? 1 : 0)
  carry = r > 9
end

p count
#=> 6
```